# Add dictionary as value of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a array of set in Python.

That is what i am trying to do with my code below

```
for doc in collection.find():
        pageType = doc.get('pageType')
        title = doc.get('title')
        _id = doc.get('_id')
        value = {'pageType' : pageType, 'id': _id}
        setValues = pageDict.get(title)
        if not setValues :
            setValues = set()
            pageDict[title] = setValues
        setValues.add(value)
```

I get following error when running it
setValues.add(value)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

I found that i cannot set the mutable value as a key of the dictionary, but i am here adding it as value of dictionary. Essentially, my value of dictionary is a set which contains another dictionary. 
How can i achieve this in python? What other data structures can i used to achieve this?

Comment: you cannot add a dict to a set which is what `setValues.add(value)` is doing, you could add the dicts to a list, also why are you changing setValues from  `pageDict.get(title)` to `setValues = set()`?

Comment: Is there any reason you need a set instead of another structure? Sets are generally used when whether or not an element is present is of concern, not the element itself.

Comment: i am using set to avoid duplicates.

Comment: just check if the element exists already, if it does then add it, if not don't, that will take care of the dups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used frozsenSet to add the value to the set and it worked

```
setValues.add(frozenSet(value.items())
```